# Using Celery as an easy alternative for Logstash

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, celery, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm developing a web application with Django+Celery, and I wish to add a simple stack that let me track events and get statistics. My first thought was Elasticsearch+Kibana, but I don't want to over complicate my deployment (I'm already using AWS Elasticsearch). So I was wonder why I need something like Logstash when I can send my events directly to Elasticsearch (in background with Celery).

If I, for instance, have to setup Redis or RabbitMQ to send messages to Logstash so it can sent to Elasticsearch, I could do the same with Celery, which I have already running.

My plan would be to call a Celery task from Django, with an array of events that would be sent to Elasticsearch. I'm using AWS SQS to connect with Celery.

I understand that with Logstash I can merge different sources, but this is not my problem right now. In fact, I'm already using AWS CloudWatch to centralize logs, which could do the same work as Logstash, but it's easier to send JSON events to Elasticsearch directly.

Surely I'm missing something, because I haven't found anyone using Celery like that. But I would like to know the reason.

My web it's very small at the moment and I should focus in other areas before complicate my deployment so much if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your message source, you don't *have* to setup a broker like redis or rabbitmq to use logstash.  For example, Filebeat -> Logstash -> Elasticsearch works well without a broker.

If you have clean json events, writing them directly to Elasticsearch is a fine idea.  The power of logstash is taking unstructured data and making nice, structured events out of it.

If celery can send your events, it sounds like a fine solution if you don't need what logstash offers.

Comment: Let me clear that my problem isn't with the setup of the broker, because I use one already for Celery. I didn't explain well in that point. My concern is why send stats to Logstash when I can send the same way to Celery which I am using already.

Your answer confirms what I suspected: Logstash is more useful when there are heterogeneous sources.